Error: `x` not equal to `y`. Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components
Tests in my R package started to fail on attributes. Let's have a minimal example:
library(testthat)
x <- structure(c("2", "0", "1", "2"), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
c("1", "5"), c("m1", "m4")))
y <- structure(c("2", "0", "1", "2"), dim = c(2L, 2L))

expect_equal(x, y, ignore_attr = TRUE)
# Error: `x` not equal to `y`.
# Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >

I only want to test the values at this stage, not the dimnames. This used to be done with expect_equivalent, but according to the expect_equivalent help (in version 3.2.1.1), the function has been deprecated and replaced with expect_equal(..., ignore_attr = TRUE). This has been the solution my code used in the past with success. Not any more. ignore_attr is an argument for waldo::compare(), which the help states is used.
Do I now need to rewrite my tests to always have matching attributes? If not, what is the current stable, recommended way to ignore attributes in tests?

Found it!
The issue is with the local edition on the new computer as is described here. expect_equal(..., ignore_attr = TRUE) is the current, stable way how to ignore attributes in tests. It is only implemented in the third edition, which means testthat >= 3.0.0.
The package DESCRIPTION thus needs to specify Config/testthat/edition: 3 to apply the current rules.
My package does that and that's why I did not encounter the issue previously. It seems that today, I loaded testthat first and doing so from outside the package set the second edition (that used the check.attributes argument as @Waldi writes). Forcing the third edition with local_edition(3) solved the problems.
local_edition(2)
expect_equal(x, y, check.attributes = FALSE)

local_edition(3)
expect_equal(x, y, ignore_attr = TRUE)


You could use the check_attributes parameter as expect_equal relies on attr.all.equal which you can turn off with this parameter :
expect_equal(x, y, check.attributes = FALSE)

